# D3.js - can clipping paths be used with d3.svg.symbol?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to draw multiple 'cross' symbols inside of a circle for use in a visualization. I'd like to draw the crosses in a 'g' tag and then apply a clipping path.

Is it possible to use clip paths with d3.svg.symbol ?

In the below example, the svg circle is masked correctly with the clip path; however the cross (the last part of the code) isn't.

Am I doing something wrong or is this not a feature?

```
var svg = d3.select("#maskingExample")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200);

svg.append("svg:clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clipper")
    .append("svg:rect")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "black")
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 45);

svg.append("g").append("svg:circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .attr("cx", 175)
    .attr("cy", 55)
    .attr("r", 50)
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipper)");

svg.append("g").append("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol()
    .size( function(d) { return 3000; })
    .type( function(d) { return d3.svg.symbolTypes[1]; }))
    .attr("transform", "translate(150, 50)")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clipper")
    .style("fill", "black");
```

Answer (score 6):

You're missing a close paren. Instead of

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clipper")
```

it should read

```
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clipper)")
```